# Is the smallest unit in Apache Spark is the block?

Tags: apache-spark

1. If it is block then, what is the desired block size? What is recommended? Is there some standard size? If not how do I know what block size should I  keep?
2. Lets say sc=streaming context.
   Is sc.awaitTermination() used in production.
   Is await for termination is the only way?
3. Lets say a block got corrupted. Since there is a fault tolerance? Is it so that the block will get recovered by taking it from another replicated block from some other executor.
4. Can different executors have different memory size?
   If so, say there are 3 executors

   ex1 = 10gb
   ex2 = 10gb
   ex3 = 5gb

Assume replication factor is configured of 2. 
How will replication work in this case. If an rdd of size lets say 8gb needs to be replicated. Then wont it fail? ex1 having say 8gb rdd size cannot be replicated into executor ex3 due to low memory? Then how fault tolerance is achieved? Does spark knows where to replicate what?Is it according to the size that it checks if it can be replicated into that particular node, if it can then replicate else dont? Then if node ex1 itself fails, then there is no fault tolerance and everything is lost?How is it handle in this scenario ?

Comment: I don't think different executors can have different memory.

Answer (score 0):

Block size is the concern of storage system like HDFS, GFS, S3, Azure Blob Storage etc. Spark is a processing engine and it just accommodated to the bloc size of the storage system to create partitions. It would create 1 partition per block so that large files are can be processed in parallel. All the storage systems have a default block size so you needn't worry about setting it though you can certainly override it.

Similarly data duplication is also a concern of storage layer. It copies a block of data into say 3 (replication factor) blocks and in case of failure it can recover data from other blocks.

Spark fits into this equation by being the processing engine operating on this distributed file system. It is responsible for distributing the compute workload where data is located, it can recover from failure on a given node which is similar to data recovery but a different beast.